# Cannot find symbol of Math class

Tags: java

I'm just learning something about the math class but I have the same error with all the methods

```
public class Math{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        float num=5.45F;

        int result=Math.round(num);

        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: @jhamon you don't need to import `Math` since its already in the `java.lang` package.

Comment: Your class name is Math and you are using Math.round. This is ambiguous and you must define a way to differentiate them

Comment: As @armagedescu mentioned class name may cause ambiguity. If you want to keep the class name same use `int result = java.lang.Math.round(num);`

Comment: I think it's not the exact error message. It is probably something like 'cannot resolve method round()..'Never use resrved words to names classes, methods, properties, etc..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're calling your own class `Math` and the method you're trying to access is from [`java.lang.Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) therefore you should use the full class name to avoid ambiguity.

```java
public class Math {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float num = 5.45F;

        int result = java.lang.Math.round(num);

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java compiler gets confused when you are trying to use your instance of your `Math`class or to use the static method `Main.round()`. To avoid such confusion you have to rename your `Math` class into something slightly different (like `MyMath`) and to make sure it won't be one of the [reserved keywords](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/j/java_reserved_words.htm) in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

You can also import the Math class at the top of your code. Like this.

```
import java.lang.Math
public class Math {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    float num = 5.45F;

    int result = Math.round(num);

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

}